# modal in master page with page has one or more <asp:Content>... error

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have a master page with a modal inside it. I want to use the modal in order to allow a customer to send an email to admin. The problem is that since I inserted the modal I get an "page has one or more `<asp:Content>` controls that do not correspond with `<asp:ContentPlaceHolder>` controls in master page" error on all pages that use this master page. When I comment the modal-code everything is ok.
What should I do?

Here is my code:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MasterPage.Master.cs"
Inherits="KAFA_SAJT.MasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title id="titl" runat="server"></title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<link href="Style/Stilovi.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="jquery-2.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../jquery-2.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="Style/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div id="banner">
    <div id="login" style="text-align: right; padding-right: 15px; padding-top: 9px;">
        <asp:Label ID="lblLogin" runat="server" ForeColor="White"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbLogin" ForeColor="White" Style="text-decoration: none;" runat="server"
            OnClick="lbLogin_Click" CausesValidation="False">
            LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" style="margin: 0">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".collapsable">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar">
                </span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Coffe Site</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse collapsable">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="~/Home.aspx" runat="server">Home</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Pregled
                    <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="~/Kafa.aspx" runat="server">Kafe</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Pregled Prodavnice</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Brendovi Kafe</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="~/Kupovina.aspx" runat="server">Kupovina</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">O nama</a></li>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalContact"
                    style="padding: 13px; text-decoration: none">
                    Kontakt</button>
                <li><a id="linkPromenaLozinke" href="~/Nalozi/ChangePassword.aspx" runat="server">Promena
                    lozinke</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" id="linkManagement" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"
                    runat="server">Management <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a id="A1" href="~/Management.aspx" runat="server">Kafe</a></li>
                        <li><a id="A2" href="~/Nalozi/LockedAccounts.aspx" runat="server">Zakljucanih</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="modalContact" class="modal fade" role="dialog" runat="server">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                    &times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">
                    Kontaktirajte nas</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="#">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="txtName">
                        Name:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" runat="server" class="form-control" id="txtName" placeholder="Enter Name" />
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="txtNameRequiredFieldValidator" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Name Required"
                            Display="Dynamic" Text="*" ControlToValidate="txtName" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="Kontakt"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="Email">
                        Email:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" runat="server" class="form-control" id="txtEmail" placeholder="Enter Email" />
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ForeColor="Red" ID="emailRequiredFieldValidator" runat="server"
                            ErrorMessage="Email Required" Display="Dynamic" Text="*" ControlToValidate="txtEmail"
                            ValidationGroup="Kontakt"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ForeColor="Red" ID="emailRegularExpressionValidator"
                            runat="server" ErrorMessage="Email not in proper format" Display="Dynamic" Text="*"
                            ControlToValidate="txtEmail" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"
                            ValidationGroup="Kontakt"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="Subject">
                        Subject:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" runat="server" class="form-control" id="txtSubject" placeholder="Enter Subject" />
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ForeColor="Red" ID="subjectRequiredFieldValidator" runat="server"
                            ErrorMessage="Subject Required" Display="Dynamic" Text="*" ControlToValidate="txtSubject"
                            ValidationGroup="Kontakt"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="Comments">
                        Comments:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <textarea runat="server" class="form-control" id="txtComments" placeholder="Enter Comment"
                            rows="4" cols="20" name="S1" />
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ForeColor="Red" ID="commentsRequiredFieldValidator" runat="server"
                            ErrorMessage="Comments Required" Display="Dynamic" Text="*" ControlToValidate="txtComments"
                            ValidationGroup="Kontakt"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <asp:Button ID="btnUpit" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Kontakt" OnClick="btnUpit_Click"
                    Text="Pošalji upit" />
                <asp:ValidationSummary ID="kontaktValidationSummary" HeaderText="Please fix the following errors"
                    ForeColor="Red" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Kontakt" Style="text-align: left" />
                <asp:Label ID="tnxLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="sadrzaj">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder> 
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this behavior is the fact that you have a form tag inside your modal markup. So your markup scheme is:

```
<body>
    <form>
        <div modal>
            <form>
            </form>
        </div modal>
    </form>
</body>
```

This is not allowed in ASP.NET, and unless you implement some dirty hacks, you have to have only one form on the ASP.NET page. So you markup should look like

```
<body>
    <form>
        <div modal>
            <!-- no form tag here -->
        </div modal>
    </form>
</body>
```